# Timeout option for Simplemembership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

Does simplemembership have an easy way to set a timeout to automatically log you out after a certain amount of time has passed while you've been inactive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleMembership doesn't provide a timeout you can configure, the authentication mechanism does.

If you are using FormsAuthentication, you can setup this timeout here:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

In the example above the timeout is set to 20 minutes. This means that the authentication cookie (containing the authentication ticket) will expire after 20 minutes of inactivity once the user is authenticated.

The membership provider is responsible to validate the user credentials, among other responsibilities. However it is not responsible of "recognizing" subsequent request for authenticated users.

Please check [this](http://brockallen.com/2012/06/04/membership-is-not-the-same-as-forms-authentication/) article so you have a better idea about what is happening behind the scene.

Comment: I have code that periodically generate requests without the need of the user clicking on anything. I set timeout to 1 minute and it did not do anything and I think it has to do with the scripts that are making requests. Is there a way around this that depends on movement/click of the mouse.

Comment: @zms6445 where are those requests originated? Client-side? How frequent?
If you are making requests to the server behind the scenes, then those request are extending your session on the server and you won't see a timeout unless you close the browser (and your auth cookie was not created to persiste across browser sessions).

Comment: There are a few ajax calls being made every few seconds. I can't decrease the frequency to something suitable for a timeout since I wouldn't get updates in a reasonable amount of time or the user is timed out too fast.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand what is the problem here.
Regardless the frequency of the calls your user sessions will expire after X minutes if they close their browsers and the cookie was set to NOT persist.

Comment: Why do you keep saying to close the browser? I'm talking about these ajax calls creating requests while a user is inactive with the webpage still open....

Comment: Your question was about _how_ to set the timeout, right? I answered that.
Now _it seems_ that what you are wondering is why you don't see the timeout effectively happening; and the answer is those requests you are doing in the background are keeping your session alive in the server.
Is there anything else I'm missing here?

Comment: No. But i did say that in the first comment. I have some ideas on how to fix this. Thanks for letting me know about the timeout option.