# User.IsInRole expires after compile in DEV or X minutes in Production

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

Based on the MVC4 Template Project I started to use Roles.

In the View where I need to give permission only to Admin Role Users like:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    // You can do it
}
else
{
    // You can't do it
}
```

When I compile in DEV, User.IsInRole("Admin") returns always false, and in production environment, it starts returning false after a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

What role is your user in DEV? If I remember correctly, the Template project use Cookie Session for authentication, but I might be wrong. If that's the case, it might be due to the expiration date of the session cookie.

Comment: Hi thanks, the role is the same. But the user don't lose access in all the [Authorize] methods after a few minutes, but lose access to the User.IsInRole code...

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint at some point and do a quick watch on the User and see if he's set with the proper value?

Comment: Yes, it's always working fine. In debug mode I'm not able to replicate the behavior of the false value when I recompile it...

Comment: What Membership provider are you using? Did you looked into your IIS configurations, for the authentication part.

Comment: I use SimpleMembership from MVC4 Template

Comment: Did you set any specific value for the timeout in the webconfig? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980413/timeout-option-for-simplemembership)

Comment: Hi, yes I have, but I need to remain the session active until the user closes the browser, or do a logoff